Doctrine field is null despite calling the setter
I have a Review Entity that is related to a User Entity through
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'reviews')]
private User $user;

and when trying to save it like this:
$review = new Review();
$review->setUserId($user->getId());
$this->entityManager->persist($review);
$this->entityManager->flush();

I receive this error:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Although I'm calling the $review->setUserId($user->getId());.
I know I can fix it by calling $review->setUser($user); as well, but I want to understand why? I mean when dd the Entity, I see the user_id is not null.
App\Entity\Database\Review {#825
  -id: null
  -user_id: 1


Why would there be a user_id property with its setter while you already have a relation user in the entity ? What is the method body for setUserId() ? What does the table definition looks like ?

Looks like you should be calling setUser(), not setUserId(). Looks like That latter method shouldn't exist.

Because I have defined this attribute in the Review Entity  #[ORM\Column(length: 11, nullable: false)] private int $user_id;

As you already mentioned, you should be using $review->setUser($user);. Don't confuse it with find($userId) of the entity's repository, which indeed takes an ID.
Behind the scenes, Doctrine ORM saves only the ID of a referenced object, so the column name becomes something like user_id in your database. In your code, however, you still use the entire object and Doctrine does the rest for you.
You can see it in the attribute of Address in this example in the official documentation where the column name for the address entity becomes address_id.
